# how to declare static array in php in the same way as in java?

Tags: java, php

in java we can delimit the space of the vector as:

```
int arr[10];
```

but in php the declaration of a array is only $arr = array();
how would I limit the space in php?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't**

However, you can add additional validation on your values like this:

```
if (strlen($str) > 10)
   $str = substr($str, 0, 7) . '...';
```